# How to stop repeating alarm at specific time

Tags: android

I am starting my alarm at 8am using below code, repeating at every 1min. I want to stop this alarm repeating at 12pm. I am starting alarm like this:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent loggerIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 08);
timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


long duration = interval * 60 * 1000;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeOff9.getTimeInMillis(), duration, loggerIntent1);
```

and stopping with this code:

```
Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), loggerIntent1);
manager.cancel(loggerIntent1);
loggerIntent1.cancel();
```

but the code for stopping causes the app to work the wrong way.
I am writing the code to stop alarm right after first alarm. is it the problem?
Do I need to write another alarm. Please guide.

Comment: Well you may need another Alarm for ending it Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829176/cancel-repeating-alarm-at-specific-time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another logic you could give a try?

Imagine this, carry on with your first portion of code where you trigger an intent for every  `duration`.

But inside your AlarmReceiver.class, that will be the one checking current time, and do the AlarmManager.cancel() when the time is over 12pm.