# cancel repeating alarm at specific time automcatically

Tags: alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to repeat alarm every one second until 3 minutes After that automatically cancel the alarm

**Here is some of the code I have been Implemented:**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)(activity.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
            mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),10000,pendingIntent);
```

I have to use **cancel()** method for cancellation. But I'm not sure where I have to implement this method?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23830373/9170086) answer might be helpful for you.
If you use Calendar, you can do it like so:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

To add 3 minutes to the current time before scheduling the 'cancellation' alarm, you can do:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
```

and then you just need to set the 'cancellation' alarm with the new time.